# Schengen visa for a stateless person

Tags: visas, schengen, eu, long-stay-visas, stateless-persons

I have applied for a long-term residence in the Czech Republic. However, as I am a stateless person residing in Uzbekistan, I was permitted to enter only 11 EU countries out of 28. Does it violate the right of free movement in the Schengen area?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of the Schengen agreement was to abolish border checks and create a single (short-stay) visa policy, which has mostly been achieved, but not necessarily to create actionable rights for non-EU citizens. There is therefore no “right to free movement” in the Schengen area as such. There is something called the “freedom of movement” in the European Union but it only applies to EU citizens and their family and is wholly unrelated to the Schengen area.

If that wasn't complicated enough, there are many exceptions and complex rules for corner cases like asylum seekers, diplomat or service passport holders or holders of special travels documents (including stateless people). The rules that apply to all these have not been harmonised. So there are no border checks between Schengen countries but that does not mean that everybody is allowed to cross internal borders.

And the possibility to issue a “limited territorial validity“ visa, only valid for some countries, was in the Schengen convention from the start (and now in article 25 of the [Schengen visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810)) so that's another perfectly legal restriction on movement within the Schengen area.

Incidentally, there are currently some serious breaches of the Schengen regulations (e.g. the way France currently treats the border with Italy, with frequent, albeit ostensibly random, checks and blatantly illegal removals of potential asylum seekers back to Italy without going through the proper channels created by the Dublin system). But the whole thing is so politically sensitive that nobody is doing anything about it (theoretically the EU Commission could initiate infringement proceedings against France but they have stayed well clear of the issue).

Comment: Thank you for the useful information! Could you please provide a link to the regulation of such limited territorial validity visa? And do you know what EU countries am I allowed to enter as a stateless person?

Comment: @FarkhodGaziev No, I don't know that but if you have a LTV, it should say so on the visa itself.

Comment: @FarkhodGaziev I added a link to the regulation.

Comment: Ok, I should receive my visa answer on next week, so maybe then it will be clear)

Comment: And I think I will not have problems if I travel through EU countries because there are no border checks, yes?

Comment: @FarkhodGaziev Yes, in practice, you can usually cross internal borders without problems. But if your document and/or your visa isn't valid in a country, there is still a risk, especially if you cross a sensitive border (e.g. trains between Italy and France) where checks are relatively frequent.

Comment: Note that the linked regulation is not applicable to long-term visas, as stated in the first article: *1. This Regulation establishes the procedures and conditions for issuing visas for transit through or intended stays in the territory of the Member States not exceeding three months in any six-month period.*

Comment: @chirlu True, I didn't notice that it was what the OP applied for. But then I am confused by the question. A residence permit is only valid for residence in a single country and replaces a visa in the other. The only thing I can imagine is that the OP travel document is not recognised by some countries… I have edited the answer slightly.

Comment: @FarkhodGaziev I think I misunderstood your question, see the discussion above. In any case, the basic fact remains that being allowed to enter a Schengen country does not necessarily mean that you have an absolute freedom of movement in the area. In your case, I guess the deciding factor would be whether your travel document is recognised everywhere. Otherwise a regular Czech residence permit should be enough to enter any Schengen country.